# Syntax -- Popen arguments

Tags: python, subprocess, cron, popen

I have a PHP script that needs to take one command-line argument.  I need to call this script from inside my python script.

```
    Popen('php simplepush.php "Here's the argument"', shell=True, cwd="/home/ubuntu/web/firestopapp.com/app")
```

^That works.  However, I want to pass a variable in the Python script instead of "Here's the argument".  But when I try:

```
    var1 = "yes"

    Popen(['php', 'simplepush.php', var1], shell=True, cwd="/home/ubuntu/web/firestopapp.com/app")
```

it no longer works.  And this is run through crontab, which is what led me to have to include the cwd argument.

I'd really appreciate any help, seems like a fairly straightforward syntactical issue.

After Eric's suggestion:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/web/mywebsite.com/app/email_parse.py", line 25, in <module>
    Popen('php simplepush.php "Here's the argument"', shell=False, cwd="/home/ubuntu/web/mywebsite.com/app")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Sihrc's solution gets me the following, so it's not a full fix.
`/bin/sh: 1: cannot open my2ndemail@gmail.com: No such file`

and here's the rest of the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import email, getpass, imaplib, os, subprocess
from subprocess import Popen

detach_dir = '.'
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
m.login("myemail@gmail.com","mypassword")
m.select('mailbox')

resp, items = m.search(None, "(UNSEEN)")
message = ""
items = items[0].split()
for emailid in items:
    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")
    email_body = data[0][1]
    mail = email.message_from_string(email_body)

    message += "["+mail["From"]+"] :" + mail["Subject"] + "\n"
    for part in mail.walk():
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
            message += part.get_payload()
        else:
            continue
    Popen('php simplepush.php ' + str(eval('message')), shell=True, cwd="/home/ubuntu/web/firestopapp.com/app")
```

Comment: @EricUrban

Tracebck from the cron's MTA response in the updated question.

Comment: @user2476581 please update your question with the traceback, it's too difficult to read as a comment

Comment: @MattDMo Edited, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Why not Popen('php simplepush.php ' + str(eval('var1')), shell = ....)

Comment: @sihrc I do believe that fixed it.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. I suppose I'll submit it as an answer..

Answer (score 0):

Detour! Dodging the issue is my specialty!

```
var1 = "yes"
Popen('php simplepush.php ' + '"' + str(eval('var1')) + '"', shell=True, cwd="/home/ubuntu/web/firestopapp.com/app")
```

Comment: So actually this works when I define var1= "yes" but it breaks when I have something that looks like the rest of the code I've edited into the question.

Comment: Yeah, I edited it into the question:
`/bin/sh: 1: cannot open my2ndemail@gmail.com: No such file`

my2ndemail@gmail.com is part of the message += operations I'm carrying out above.  And if I simply `print message` before Popen, the whole string prints properly.

Comment: I'm sorry, I pasted in a different version.  Using eval with quotes still gives me the error I gave above, where it tries to open the string instead of using it as an argument.

Comment: At this point, I would just recommend writing the message to external file and reading it in php.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import email, getpass, imaplib, os, subprocess
import shlex
from subprocess import Popen

detach_dir = '.'
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
m.login("myemail@gmail.com","mypassword")
m.select('mailbox')

resp, items = m.search(None, "(UNSEEN)")
message = ""
items = items[0].split()
for emailid in items:
    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")
    email_body = data[0][1]
    mail = email.message_from_string(email_body)

    message += "["+mail["From"]+"] :" + mail["Subject"] + "\n"
    for part in mail.walk():
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
            message += part.get_payload()
        else:
            continue
    for pdir in os.getenv('PATH'):
        if os.access("{}/{}".format(pdir, 'php'), os.X_OK):
            phppath = "{}/{}".format(pdir, 'php')
            break
    cmd = '{} simplepush.php "{}"'.format(phppath, message)
    Popen(shlex.split(cmd),
          cwd="/home/ubuntu/web/firestopapp.com/app")
```